# Add the computed percentage of area of polygon into the table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, shapefile, spatial-query

I am trying to find the percentage of the polygon inside the other polygon and wanted to write it into the existing table. I have calculated the area but I cannot add it to the existing table.

```
SELECT 
  ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer) AS intersection,   
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer))/ST_Area(r.geom)*100 
FROM public."Residential" r, public."Operation" o 
WHERE ST_Intersects(o.buffer,ST_MakeValid(r.geom));
```

I have tried this to add it to the existing table,

```
ALTER TABLE public."Operation" ADD COLUMN res_percent double precision;
UPDATE public."Operation"  
SELECT      
  ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer) AS intersection,   
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer))/ST_Area(r.geom)*100)) 
FROM public."Residential" r, public."Operation" o 
WHERE ST_Intersects(o.buffer,ST_MakeValid(r.geom));
```

I am getting an error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"

I just want to add the percentage of the residential polygon (geom) inside the buffer region into a new column in the Operation table.

I have added the fiddle below for the model of the question,

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=caa30c97705be59624c95659d82c7892)

What I am doing wrong here, How this can be rectified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot combine select and update statements like that. You rather have to join both tables in the `update` query to calculate the area, e.g.

```
UPDATE public."Operation" o
SET res_percent = 
   ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer))/ST_Area(r.geom)*100
FROM public."Residential" r
WHERE ST_Intersects(o.buffer, ST_MakeValid(r.geom));
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the syntax error but doesn't necessarily to do the desired calculation.

There is no such syntax as `update . . . select`.  I am guessing you intend:

```
UPDATE public."Operation" o
    SET res_percent = ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom), o.buffer)) / (ST_Area(r.geom)*100)
    FROM public."Residential" r
    WHERE ST_Intersects(o.buffer, ST_MakeValid(r.geom));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but 'ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer) AS intersection, '
this query is not fulfilled. How to integrate it with that ?

Comment: @Aravinth . . . Here is a db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3214bd6b970628e580b3032396dc4804.

Comment: Kindly see the first query which I have done gives the percentage of the residential inside the buffer, the query you have updated gives a different result in percentage. Kindly can you explain.

Comment: the result of the percentage is like 0.01 its definitely not that low, kindly can you help me with that.